# Is this a homogeneous polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

If $f(ta,tb) = f(a,b)$ $\forall t \neq 0$, then can we conclude that $f$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree 1?

Comment: All constant functions satisfy this.

Comment: Except constants, yes!

Comment: A homogeneous degree $1$ polynomial would satisfy $f(ta, tb)=t^1 f(a, b)$.

Answer (score 1):

Homogeneous of degree $1$ would be $f(ta,tb) = t^1f(a,b)$. In your case you have that $f(ta,tb) = f(a,b)=t^0f(a,b)$. This would mean homogeneous of degree $0$.

[Here](http://faculty.swosu.edu/michael.dougherty/DiffEqI/lecture05.pdf) are some nice lecture notes and finer details on "functions homogeneous of degree $0$".